# Powershell Create csv file without empty line

Tags: powershell

I created `csv` file using `PowerShell`, I used the below command its create `csvfile` capture `ipaddress`, please help me with right code in `PowerShell` without empty line.

```
$IpAddress = Get-NetIPAddress -InterfaceAlias WI* -AddressFamily Ipv4 

$IpAddress.IPv4Address > ../testData/Ip_${env:COMPUTERNAME}.csv
```

I am expecting help from you to write code without creating empty line in `csv` file.

Comment: Where is empty line?  Are there more than one empty line?  It may be the wrong return is at the end of each line (0xC 0x0A) instead of just 0x0A.

Comment: Please [format your post properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Answer (score 1):

You're not creating a *CSV* file, you're creating a *plain-text file without a header* with an IPv4 address on each line, given that you're not using [`Export-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Export-Csv).

If some of the adapters returned don't have IPv4 addresses, you can filter out the resulting empty lines as follows (spread across multiple lines for readability:

```bash
@(
  (Get-NetIPAddress -InterfaceAlias WI* -AddressFamily Ipv4).IPv4Address
) -ne ''  > ../testData/Ip_${env:COMPUTERNAME}.txt
```